# How to install Intellij IDEA 15 on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: software-installation, 15.10, intellij

I have *Intellij IDEA 15* (Community) in Downloads folder.
The file name is `ideaIC-15.0.3.tar.gz`. My operation system is *Ubuntu 15.10* for developers. Can anyone help me install it? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

1. Unpack the IntelliJ IDEA distribution archive that you downloaded to
    where you wish to install the program. We will refer to this destination
    location as your {installation home} below.
2. Open a console and cd into "{installation home}/bin" and type:

   ./idea.sh

   to start the application. As a side effect, this will initialize various
    configuration files in the ~/.IntelliJIdea15 directory.
3. [OPTIONAL] Add "{installation home}/bin" to your PATH environment
    variable so that you may start IntelliJ IDEA from any directory.
4. [OPTIONAL] To adjust the value of the JVM heap size, create
     ~/.IntelliJIdea15/idea.vmoptions (or idea64.vmoptions
     if using a 64-bit JDK), and set the -Xms and -Xms paramters. To see how
     to do this, you can reference the vmoptions file under
     "{installation home}/bin" as a model.

   [OPTIONAL] Changing the location of "config" and "system" directories

   ---

   By default, IntelliJ IDEA stores all your settings under the ~/.IntelliJIdea15/config
   directory and uses ~/.IntelliJIdea15/system as a data cache.
   If you want to change these settings,
5. Open a console and cd into ~/.IntelliJIdea15/
6. Create the file "idea.properties" and open it in an editor. Set the
    idea.system.path and/or idea.config.path variables as desired, for
    example:

   idea.system.path=~/custom/system
    idea.config.path=~/custom/config
7. Note that we recommend to store data cache ("system" directory) on a disk
    with at least 1GB of free space.

Enjoy!

-IntelliJ IDEA Development Team

Comment: Why is this so hard? Why is it not in Software Centre?